# Javascript with Promise output whenever is ready

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code:

```js
console.log(1);
var pro = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let myDate;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    let date = new Date();
    myDate = date
  }
  resolve(myDate);

});
pro.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
console.log(2);

//output:
//1
// after 2 seconds:
//2
// Date
```

number 2 logs before date.
but it logs whenever date is ready.
why?

As we use async to speedup our codes, but in the above code, we must still wait... the just difference now is priority of outputing the codes.
My expected result is:

1
2
// after few seconds:
Date

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(1);
var pro = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

let myDate; 
setTimeOut(()=>{
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { 
    let date = new Date(); 
    myDate = date 
} 
},0)

resolve(myDate); 

});
pro.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
console.log(2);
```

did you try time out

Comment: @dev725 - the `undefined` is the *result* of `console.log(2)` - try doing just that in the console - the `undefined` would not be output to the console if you didn't run this in the console

Comment: the problem of this answer is that ```resolve(myDate)``` is out of ```setTimeout```

Answer (score 0):

The promise will resolve async, but the resolver (the code you run when constructing the promise) is executed right away.

This means that before executing `console.log(2)` the costly loop is executed. This is why you see the delay.

You can use `setTimeout` to move the execution at a later time.

```js
console.log(1);
var pro = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    let myDate;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
     let date = new Date();
     myDate = date
   }
   resolve(myDate);
  }, 100)
});
pro.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
console.log(2);
```

Comment: However ```setTimeout``` will remove the delay, but if you do the same without Promise, the result is the same. see: https://hastebin.com/ixameyolun.js thus, I have not understood yet why async is useful while we must wait!